# Laravel Varbox get drafted items programatically

Tags: laravel, eloquent, publish

I've created a `draftable` custom entity. I noticed that from the admin I can save it as a draft or publish it.

However, I'm wondering how can I fetch all my `drafted` or `published` records and how can I determine if a single record instance is `drafted` or `published`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given what you've said, I'm assuming you're already using the `Varbox\Traits\IsDraftable` trait on your model.

You can make use of the query scopes that trait exposes in order to only fetch your drafted or published records like so:

```php
$onlyPublishedRecords = YourModel::withoutDrafts()->get();

$onlyDraftedRecords = YourModel::onlyDrafts()->get();
```

Here's the documentation part for reference: https://varbox.io/docs/1.x/draft-records#query-scope

---

To answer your second part of the question, you can check if a record is drafted or published by using the `isDrafted` method:

```php
$model = YourModel::find($id);

dump($model->isDrafted()); // true or false
```

Here's the documentation part for reference: https://varbox.io/docs/1.x/draft-records#check-if-draft